# Как добавить везде IGNORE

Tags: php

Переехал на другой сервер, заметил что запросы к базе типа UPDATE или INSERT не выполняются, нужно делать так

```
UPDATE IGNORE
```

то есть добавить **IGNORE**

у меня очень много файлов с запросами. возможно ли как-то сделать чтобы IGNORE везде присутствовал без редактирования каждого файла.

php 5.3

Comment: При чём тут тег `PHP`, если вопрос по серверу БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в my.cnf установлен строгий режим, нечто вроде

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```

Их надо убрать и перезапустить MySQL.

Comment: а где это редактируется не подскажете?

Comment: Стандартно в /etc/my.cnf